# How to focus or select a cell in Excel

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2007

How to focus a cell in Excel VSTO using C# or to select first cell using C# in VSTO?

Comment: This question has been correctly answered you should mark it as answered.

Comment: Refer [this article](http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/Excel-extensions-with-VSTO-power-tools.aspx) also

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
Excel.Worksheet activeSheet = ThisAddIn.ExcelApplication.ActiveSheet;
var range = activeSheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");
range.Select();
```

*ThisAddIn is the name of my test project.*

Comment: You can also add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Extensions;   so that you can do   var range = activeSheet.Range("A1"); in place of the 2nd line.

Comment: An important thing to note here is that you can only call Select on the active sheet.  So if you need to select a cell in something other than the currently active sheet, you'll need to call Activate on it first.

Answer (score 3):

To select the A2 cell, for example:

```
Excel.Worksheet Worksheet = excel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
Worksheet.get_Range([1,2], System.Reflection.Missing.Value).Select();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 Excel.Application ExcelApp = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
            Excel.Workbook book = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook;
            Excel.Worksheet sheet = book.ActiveSheet;
            Excel.Range ExcelRange = sheet.get_Range("A1");
            ExcelRange.Select();
```

Comment: You realize that was 7 years ago?  What does your answer add that is not already in the proposed answers?  Explain your solution at least.