# Opening Excel with the selection of cells

Tags: c#, asp.net

When i am exporting the Excel by asp.net c# the cursor of the excel is somewhere. I want the excel should be selected Particular cells...Is it possible in programmatically ?

Comment: How exactly are you exporting it to excel? Pretty fundamental to the question...

Comment: Using c# asp.net normal method only ..When I opening the excel sheet the cell index is "J34" .. I Need to set as "A1"

Comment: *"normal method only"* are you referring to COM interop?

Comment: Sorry James . I am new to technology . But I have creates that application with the reference of the following link
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-To-Word-Excel-PDF-CSV-Formats-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: Ah ok, as far as I am aware there is no way to determine a cell selection using the header approach.

Comment: It helps [How to focus a cell in Excel VSTO using C#? How to select first cell using C# in VSTO?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513968/how-to-focus-a-cell-in-excel-vsto-using-c-how-to-select-first-cell-using-c-sha?answertab=active#tab-top